How to disable the Brightness Slider in Windows 11 System Tray?
I'm looking for a way to disable or remove the brightness slider that appears in the system tray (Quick Settings) on Windows 11.


Checked Settings > Display but didn’t find an option to disable the
slider.
Explored potential registry tweaks but couldn’t find any official references or keys
related to the brightness slider.
Looked into group policies but didn’t see any options for this feature.

What is a documented way or a workaround (registry, policy, or other method) to achieve this? I’m open to using third-party tools if needed.
Any guidance would be appreciated

I don’t believe there is a way to disable this functionality. I cannot think of a single policy that would control the brightness of a display.

Have you tried https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/no-brightness-slider-in-win11.html ??
